# How do I split the value of a list to 2 separate columns in R?

Tags: r, geolocation, data-analysis

I used snscrape to get the geolocation of tweets for mapping them on the world map. The resulted coordinates come in format {'longitude': -70.7729481, 'latitude': 42.0616232}.

How do I split the list into two columns like?

| longitude | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| -70.7729 | 42.06162 |

I've tried unlist, read.table and few other ways I could find online but none of them work. It usually just ends up as

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| {'longitude': -70.7729481 | 'latitude': 42.0616232} |

Comment: What's up with tagging `R` questions with `python`? Don't spam tags please.

Comment: @Julien because snscrape is a tool used in python. That's how I got the data. Sorry

Comment: can you paste the results of `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you deal with json data, you perhaps can do it right away from your json string.

```
library(jsonlite)

str <- '{"longitude" : -70.7729481, "latitude" : 42.0616232}'
data.frame(fromJSON(str))

#     longitude   latitude
# 1 -70.7729481 42.0616232
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
string <- "{'longitude': -70.7729481, 'latitude': 42.0616232}"
data.frame(reticulate::py_eval(string))

  longitude latitude
1 -70.77295 42.06162
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.